# Kendo Grid auto resize by number of rows

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I display fixed number of rows in kendo grid regardless of window size change?
I need to display 10 rows regardless of window resizes.
In order to do this, I need to re-calculate the number of rows and display 10 rows only back inside the grid. My requirement is to calculate the rows to display correctly in the grid. (in fact, I have search on internet and seems can't find any examples/articles, if you have any please share with me too ). My current solution has no error in my opinion, but still incorrect??? . Can someone help me find errors and correct me? Moreover if I insert some items above grid, the wrapper and data items(grid) becomes incorrect totally.

I need some insight and/or code-examples on this matter.
Much appreciated for the help.

My current codes for the resizing grid is as follow:

```
function resizeGrid() {
    var gridElement = $("#grid"),
        dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content"),
        gridHeight = gridElement.innerHeight(),
        otherElements = gridElement.children().not(".k-grid-content"),
        otherElementsHeight = 0;
    otherElements.each(function(){
        otherElementsHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    dataArea.height(gridHeight - otherElementsHeight);
}

function resizeWrapper() {
     $("#outerWrapper").height($('#body').innerHeight());
    }
```

and call the functions of both of them:

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resizeWrapper();
    resizeGrid();
  });
```

This is my datasource and schema:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger("resize");
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({     
      dataSource: {
                            data: [

                              { userId: 11111, No: 1, isActive:true, date: new Date('12/12/2005 12:30 AM'), from: 'A', sm: 'testing', art: 'Shipped on', due: new Date('12/19/2005 11:30 PM')},
      { userId: 22340, No: 2, isActive:true, date: new Date('12/12/2005 12:30 AM'), from: 'A', sm: 'test0', art: 'Shipped on', due: new Date('12/19/2005 11:30 PM')},
      .....
      ],

                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                              userId: { editable: true },
                              date: { filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker"}},
                              isActive:false,
                              No: { editable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },

                sortable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                resizable: true,
                filterable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },               
                columns: [
                  { field: 'No' ,width: 50 },
    { field: 'userId', title: 'ID', template:"<span class=ul>#=userId#</span> </br> <span class='pie'>1/5</span>", width:60 }      ,  
                  { field: "isActive", 
            headerTemplate: '!',
            template: '<span class="k-icon k-i-circle Unicode: e308" style="color: green; font-size: 28px;"></span> </br> <div class="div1"></div>', filterable:false , width: 40  },
    ......              
    ]        
    });        
  });
```

Here is my kendo link: http://dojo.telerik.com/aviQU/6

Answer (score 0):

Why not tell the grid to use a page size of 10? No need to recalculate sizes.

Set the data source's page size when you configure the grid.

Or are you setting (CSS/JS) the height of the grid somewhere that is causing it to resize?

Comment: yes it is more straight forward that way, I could easily control row number by setting page size to datasource(in my code I have done that too ) But it was one of the requirements(calculate by row numbers) for me to accomplish. I've found this link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1735 but it is for angular and I couldn't understand to apply inside my dojo. But I guess it is a lot similar. Currently I am not setting any custom height in CSS/JS.

Comment: @NewBie in that case I think you need to revise the question. Currently it says you want 10 rows whatever the window size. But it sounds like 10 is an example: you need to tell us what the requirement is *in the question* (content in comments is too easy to miss).

Comment: Hi Richard I've posted new question thread with full requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107051/display-kendo-grid-by-calculating-row-heights-and-other-components